# Regex replace in Python: Convert named group to integer

Tags: python, regex

While replacing a pattern in a string,
**I specifically need the integer/long value of matching named group.**

Example of case and what I tried:

```
status = {1:'foo', 23:'bar'}
re.sub(
    '<status>(?P<id>\d+)',
    status.get(int(r'\g<id>')), # ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\g<id>'
    # status.get(int(r'\g<id>'.decode())), # ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\g<id>'
    # status.get('%d' % r'\g<id>'), # %d format: a number is required, not str
    'Tom ran: from <status>1 to <status>23')
```

Normal casting works well with raw string `int(r'22')` but it doesn't work in above?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Please show a complete, correct example. http://sscce.org/

Comment: I have now added the errors raised in all the tried attempts in above question. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is, there's no magic in regex substitutions.  Things like r'\g<id>' are just ordinary strings, that literally contain a backslash, a 'g', and a couple angle brackets.  Inside the re.sub() method is code that parses those strings.

If you try to pass the string to something else (like int()) before it ever gets to re.sub(), then int() sees the literal string with the backslashes and the g and the angle brackets and has no idea what to make of it.   That's why you need to use the lambda form, as thg435 demonstrated.

Comment: Aaaha! That explains it well in simple words.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
re.sub(
    '<status>(?P<id>\d+)',
    lambda m: status.get(int(m.group('id'))),
    'Tom ran: from <status>1 to <status>23')
```

> If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string. @ http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub