# How can I return multiple instances of the same span within one div?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking at  [this site](https://www.rotoballer.com/fantasy-baseball-daily-projected-starting-mlb-lineups). What I'm trying to do is to create a .csv that has columns for the away team, away starter, away pitcher handedness, and then individual columns for each away batter and each away batter's handedness -- and then the same for the home teams.

Here's what I have so far, based off [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csj1RoLTMIA):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from csv import reader

url = 'https://www.rotoballer.com/fantasy-baseball-daily-projected-starting-mlb-lineups'

def get_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def parse(soup):
    daily_lineups = []
    card = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'mlbMatchup clear'})
    for lineup in card:
        lineup = {
            'away_team': lineup.find('div', {'class': 'teams'}).find('span',{'class': 'away'}).text,
            'away_pitcher': lineup.find('div', {'class': 'away'}).find('a').text,
            'away_pitcher_hand': lineup.find('div', {'class': 'away'}).find('span', {'class': 'handed'}).text,
           # 'away_lineup': lineup.find('div', {'class': 'lineup'}).text.replace('PREMIUM','').replace("Today's Rating", ''),
            'away_player': lineup.find('span', {'class': 'entryInfo'}).find('a').text,
            'away_player_hand': lineup.find('span', {'class': 'entryInfo'}).find('span', {'class': 'handed'}).text,
            'home_team': lineup.find('div', {'class': 'teams'}).find('span',{'class': 'home'}).text,
            'home_pitcher': lineup.find('div', {'class': 'home'}).find('a').text,
            'home_pitcher_hand': lineup.find('div', {'class': 'home'}).find('span', {'class': 'handed'}).text,
                    
         }
        daily_lineups.append(lineup)
    return daily_lineups

def output(daily_lineups):
    lineupsdf =  pd.DataFrame(daily_lineups)
    lineupsdf.to_csv('lineups.csv', index=False)
    print('Saved to CSV')
    return

soup = get_data(url)
daily_lineups = parse(soup)
output(daily_lineups)
```

If I use the script as is, I can get the teams, pitchers and handedness just fine. I can get the first player in the lineup and their handedness. I can't seem to make it get every instance of the entryInfo span class.

If I comment out the player and player_hand lines and just use the lineup div (in the away_lineup line), I can get the full lineup that exports to one big cell when I import it into Excel instead of breaking it out into individual columns.

Using either method, I can get the away team players (which appear first in the div) but not the home team players.

Here's the result with the script as posted:

[image]

Here's the result using the away_lineup line taking the entire "lineup" div:

[image]

And here's what I'm shooting for (truncated to just two players per team but I'd want to pull all nine):

[image]

I know I'm likely missing something pretty obvious and basic here, but I've tried combing through this site and found similar situations that were solved by using findnext or siblings, but no luck for me. I tried introducing a second, nested for loop, and I can't seem to figure out how to make it sing.

tl;dr: There are eighteen identical span classes within the div I'm targeting to scrape on a page, and I can't figure out how to get them all and properly sort them out.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show a couple of rows of expected output please?

Comment: Of course. Those sample results edited in.

Comment: Left side is always away?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to process during a loop over matches as shown below. I grab player lists within single columns, then split those into separate columns, and finally use regex to rename those columns and to increment player numbering to start from 1. You need to just apply a column sort order at end.

Also, you need to decide what to do about TB @ LAA, where there are two number sixes in source. Current method below will increment, rather than tie, on that number. You could write some further regex, based on examples below, to handle that, based on the assumption that there should only be numbers 1-9, and seeing 6 extracted twice from html.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.rotoballer.com/fantasy-baseball-daily-projected-starting-mlb-lineups'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.text, "lxml")
matches = soup.select('.mlbMatchup')
results = []

for match in matches:
    
    away_team = match.select_one('.away').text
    away_pitcher = match.select_one('.away a').text
    away_pitcher_hand = match.select_one('.away .handed').text
    away_player = [i.text for i in match.select('.lineup:nth-child(3) .entryInfo [href*=player]')]
    away_player_hand = [i.text for i in match.select('.lineup:nth-child(3) .entryInfo .handed')]
    
    home_team = match.select_one('.home').text
    home_pitcher = match.select_one('.home a').text
    home_pitcher_hand = match.select_one('.home .handed').text
    home_player = [i.text for i in match.select('.lineup:nth-child(4) .entryInfo [href*=player]')]
    home_player_hand = [i.text for i in match.select('.lineup:nth-child(4) .entryInfo .handed')]
    
    row = [away_team, away_pitcher, away_pitcher_hand, away_player, away_player_hand,
           home_team, home_pitcher, home_pitcher_hand, home_player, home_player_hand]
    results.append(row)

cols = ['away_team', 'away_pitcher', 'away_pitcher_hand', 'away_player', 'away_player_hand',
        'home_team', 'home_pitcher', 'home_pitcher_hand', 'home_player', 'home_player_hand']

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = cols)

splits = ['away_player', 'away_player_hand', 'home_player', 'home_player_hand']

for split in splits:
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df[split].values.tolist()).add_prefix(split)
    df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
    df.drop([split], axis=1, inplace=True)

# re-number to start from 1 using lambda idea from @georg https://stackoverflow.com/a/9925319
df.columns = [re.sub(r'player(?P<g1>\d+)$', lambda m: 'player' + str(int(m.group('g1')) + 1), i) for i in df.columns]   
df.columns = [re.sub(r'(?P<g1>_hand)(?P<g2>\d+)', lambda m: str(int(m.group('g2')) + 1) + m.group('g1'), i) for i in df.columns]     
# print(df.head())
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Plenty for me to dig into here. I wasn't even close!

Comment: you are most welcome. Let me know if you want more detail etc.....